# The slot of readMessageFromTCPServer could not be triggered sometimes after receiving message

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt creator 5.5.1 in windows 7.

The compiler is VC 2010 32 bits.

I have written a socket client. It could connect well but sometimes its `readyRead()` signal could not be triggered after receiving message from server. So the `readMessageFromTCPServer()` slot could not be triggered and the thread could not run.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushBtn_LoadCfg_clicked()
{  
 if (tcpClient == NULL)                      
  {
    tcpClient = new QTcpSocket;
    tcpClient->connectToHost(ui->txtIPServer->text(),ui->txtPortServer- 
    >text().toInt());
    QObject::connect(tcpClient,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, 
    SLOT(readMessageFromTCPServer()));
  }
}


void MainWindow::readMessageFromTCPServer()
{

    std::string r="start";

    QByteArray qba;

    qba= tcpClient->readAll();
    if (qba.contains(r.c_str()))
    {
        cout<<"thread run";
    }

}
```

When I tried to debug this program. I put a break point at this line: `Sleep(800)`, but sometimes this slot could not be triggered after receiving message from socket server. And I have checked that the socket is still connected, why the slot could not be triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code. You will only have the slot triggered once.

- Get rid of those `Sleep` commands. There is no good reason to use it if you are doing it in the main thread.
- `QByteArray qba= NULL;` makes no sense. `QByteArray qba;` is ok.
- `while(1)` means ***forever***. You should break the loop at some point. Actually, you do not need this loop at all. Put the code inside this loop out of it and remove the loop. When the `readyRead()` signal is emitted, it means that there is some data to be read. You can `readAll()` that data chunk, do your stuff and return.
- There is no guarantee that you will get your entire message in one round. So, in some circumstances, you may get "St" in one signal and "art" in another. So, you should implement your own buffering mechanism for such a situation. It may happen on big chunks of data. If you are sure that you are getting very short packages, then it's ok to rely on the internal buffer of QTCPSocket.

Comment: I have followed all your suggestion.

Comment: I have rewrite the question

Comment: @Django, you should not do thag. revert the changes